# PHP Regex to match a number

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract the integer `1425` from the string `$123 / 123 - 1425ft² - Some random message`. However I can only extract `5` and not `1425` with the code below.

Being bad at regex, I used `*` to match multiple digits.

Any suggestions what went wrong? Thank you!

**PHP**

```
$text = '$123 / 123 - 1425ft² - Some random message';
$pattern = '/ ([0-9])*ft²/s';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  1425ft²
    [1] => 5
)
```

Comment: Move the capturing group to capture all the digits: `'/ ([0-9]+)ft²/s'`

Comment: You need to move the star *inside* the parentheses, so that the capturing group `()` contains all digits that were matched.

Comment: Why don't you just use `/(1425)/` as a pattern?

Comment: @Oswald are you serious or joking? You sure made me laugh.

Comment: @Oswald looooool! if he knew that he is looking for `1425` why would he need a regexp!?

Comment: So you're saying the `1425` is just an example? I wonder what else might be an example. Are the separators '/' and '-' also just examples? Does `Some random message` contain digits, maybe even separators? Is `ft²` always there literally? Can it be part of `Some random message`? These questions need to be addressed before devising a regular expression.

Comment: Sorry guys for the confusion, `'/ ([0-9]+)ft²/s'` works great for what I am trying to solve.

Comment: @Nyxynyx don't be sorry, just accept the answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slight change to your pattern

`$pattern = '/ ([0-9]*)ft²/';`

or if there has to be at least one matched number

`$pattern = '/ ([0-9]+)ft²/';`

Comment: The `/s` modifier is not useful here.

Comment: agreed and removed, it was from the original pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '$123 / 123 - 1425ft² - Some random message';
$pattern = '/([0-9]+)ft²/s';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
```

Use the above code. I have test it. Its working fine.

Comment: `([0-9]+)*`: 2 layers of repetition = bad stuff.

Comment: I don't know what the regex is used for, but I can make that regex runs into backtracking hell and hit the backtracking limit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$text = '$123 / 123 - 1425ft² - Some random message';
$pattern = '/(?P<number>\d+)ft²/';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);

echo $matches['number'];
```

Comment: This is slightly different from the OP's regex. OP's regex exclude the case where the match is at the start of the string, and fix the space character before the numbers. Yours will allow a match at the beginning of the string, but also allow a match when there are other characters in front of the numbers.

Comment: It will match any number before ft², that is what OP asked for.

Comment: I only describe the difference. Whether it is something OP asks for or not is up to OP.